# Bonded neutral on the generator if wiring to a sub-panel?

Tags: grounding-and-bonding

I wish to install a line from the generator to a sub-panel that has disconnect. The sub-panel feeds the whole house. The line would use a 30amp CB with interlock kit. The sub-panels ground and neutrals are separate, should the generator have a bonded neutral or a floating neutral?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The generator must have a floating neutral.  This arrangement will rely on the neutral-ground bond at the main panel.   You don't want two neutral-ground bonds in the system.

FYI to readers: with subpanels, the feeder between main and subpanel must be 4-wire with separate neutral and ground, and the neutrals isolated in the subpanel. We are talking North America (from context) in this conversation.

Comment: The disconnect CB would isolate the power wires from the main panel. To clarify what you said, the generator wiring ground wire would connect to the ground bus and the neutral wire would connect to the neutral bus, completing those circuits back to the main panel. Is this correct and would it meet code not to back-feed the utility?